# What is a Southpaw Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSgFH.png) series started by [JLee][2] with a special brand of [Phrase™][3] and [Word™][4] puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Southpaw Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| SOUTHPAW WORD™ | NOT SOUTHPAW WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| FAST | QUICK |
| SCREW | NAIL |
| EVADERS | DEFLATERS |
| SWEET | SOUR |
| TREATS | TRICKS |
| AVERTED | WELCOMED |
| REAR | FRONT |
| CREED | MANTRA |
| @45266 | COMMUNITY |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
SOUTHPAW WORD™, NOT SOUTHPAW WORD™
FAST, QUICK
SCREW, NAIL
EVADERS, DEFLATERS
SWEET, SOUR
TREATS, TRICKS
AVERTED, WELCOMED
REAR, FRONT
CREED, MANTRA
@45266, COMMUNITY
```

Comment: Is it Southpaw or lonely? thanks

Comment: How on Earth do people catch my mistakes within the span of 30 seconds?! Thanks, @OmegaKrypton.

Comment: With the last line as it stands, this is geographically-biased; in particular, here in the UK @45266 is _not_ a Southpaw Word.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Is that because of (n qvssrerag xrlobneq ynlbhg)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Southpaw word

> is typed with only the left hand on a keyboard.

Comment: You've got it! I'll wait to accept (on a matter of principle), but I doubt anyone will have a better solution- after all, this was the intended solution!