# Commonality between these words 2

Tags: pattern, word-property

My friend sent me an email this time. I had only just woken up, and was very sleepy (my head actually dipped down many times, but that helped me with this new problem.) It went like this:

Well, well, well. Good work with the first one, although it wasn't all that hard, was it? Well, here's another one. Find out the commonality with these words; the vowels are part of the problem, but not the whole key!

• Swerve

• Ted

• Rated

• Fatter

• Wade

• Gassed

• Scarf

• Qatar

• Trade

• Texas

• Vat

• Tracer

• Waxed

• Fade

• Serf

• Vets

I sent a reply email back to my friend before heading downstairs for a cup of coffee. Can you solve this one? What is the key to his second riddle?

Comment: I get the feeling you would like the ['What is a... Word?'](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aq) series of questions that has done the rounds on Puzzling over the last few years. In fact this puzzle is pretty much the same as [What is a Southpaw Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81340/what-is-a-southpaw-word)!

Comment: I didn't know there were puzzles specifically about this. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these words

> can be typed using just the letters on the left hand side of a (QWERTY) keyboard.